# msi installation without showing .exe file extension

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, file-extension

I've created an MSI file for the installation of my app and everything works just dandy except for one thing - when it installs to a device, it shows the `.exe` file extension.  I've gone in to the installation properties to try to remove the extension, but the properties are READ ONLY.  I just don't know where to look to get rid of the file extension.  Any help is appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Please improve this question or it is bound to be closed. What device are you referring to? What is the nature of your app? What technologies does it use? Is the picture above from Visual Studio? What did you use to compile your MSI file? WiX?

Comment: Installing to Windows; Nature of the app is irrelevant; Yes, the image is from Visual Studio; I used the VS compiler to compile the MSI...